# Graphing Equations in Overleaf

Tags: math-mode

I am trying to graph lines in Overleaf. Can someone help me make the lines y = 2x, y=1/2 x in the first quartile? Thanks.

Comment: Are you familiar with [tikz](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/TikZ_package)?

Comment: No, not really.

Answer (score 2):

This is done with [pgfplots](https://ftp.yz.yamagata-u.ac.jp/pub/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/pgfplots/doc/pgfplots.pdf). Maybe it helps you getting started.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \begin{axis}[] 
            
            \addplot[red]{2*x};
            \addplot[blue]{x/2};
            
        \end{axis}
    
        \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

or just with [TIKZ](https://www.bu.edu/math/files/2013/08/tikzpgfmanual.pdf):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[->] (-3, 0) -- (3, 0) node[right] {$x$};
        \draw[->] (0, -3) -- (0, 3) node[above] {$y$};
        \draw[scale=0.5, domain=-3:3, smooth, variable=\x, blue] plot ({\x}, {2*\x});
        \draw[scale=0.5, domain=-6:6, smooth, variable=\y, red]  plot ({\y}, {\y/2});
    \end{tikzpicture}
    

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: he deavtivated right after saying thanks, lol ^^

Comment: just curious about auto-scaling of `pgfplots`. Here is my try (combine some of them) `\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis} 
%\addplot[magenta]{x^3};
\addplot[magenta,domain=-pi:pi]{x^3};
\addplot[blue,smooth,domain=-pi:pi]{sin(deg(x))};
%\addplot[red,smooth,domain=-180:180]{cos(x)};
%\addplot[red,smooth,domain=-pi:pi] {cos(deg(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}`