# How to draw this function?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

How can I draw this function in LaTeX?

[image]

[image]

Edit: i did something good but fig 1 does not work how i want

```
%---------------------------FIGURE 1-------------------------------------------\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        %----------------------ASSSI---------------------
        \draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (4,0) node[anchor=north west] {tempo};
        \draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (0,4) node[anchor=south east] {velocità};
        %---------------------- MOTO --------------------  
        \draw[smooth, domain=0:4,thick] 
        plot (\x,{exp(-\x)}) node [right]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

%----------------------------- END FIGURE 1----------------------------------------------
%----------------------------- FIGURE 2--------------------------------------------------

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
        %----------------------ASSSI---------------------
        \draw[thick,->] (0.33,0) -- (4.33,0) node[anchor=north west] {tempo};
        \draw[thick,->] (0.33,0) -- (0.33,4) node[anchor=south east] {posizione};
        %---------------------- MOTO --------------------  
        \draw[smooth, domain=0.335:4,thick] 
        plot (\x,{3-(1/(\x))}) node [right]{};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
%----------------------------END FIGURE 2----------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Do you have the formulæ for these functions?

Comment: If you have the function you can try it with this answer here: [Graphing Equations in Overleaf](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/586444/224762)

Comment: What exactly in figure 1 is wrong? Be specific please so that we can help fix the specific problem. Is figure 2 OK?

Comment: Figure 2 is Ok, figure 1 i want that the function starts higher in y axe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[varwidth,
               border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% ASSSI
\draw[<->] (0,4) -- node[left] {tempo}      (0,0) 
                 -- node[below] {velocità}  (4,0);
% MOTO 
\draw[domain=0:3.5, samples=31, thick] plot (\x,{3*exp(-\x)});
\end{tikzpicture}


\begin{tikzpicture}
% ASSSI
\draw[<->] (0,4) -- node[left]  {tempo}     (0,0)
                 -- node[below] {posizione} (4,0);
% MOTO
\draw[domain=0:3.5, samples=31, thick] plot (\x, {3-3*exp(-\x)}); % <--- corrected
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot, I cant upvote at the moment becouse i haven't enought reputaton but i will when i can.

Comment: @Livoree, no problem, however, if you liked you can already accept answer ;-)

Comment: Done , ty again :)